# Como recuperar el foco si se desactiva el formulario

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario que siempre se quede por delante de otras aplicaciones, esa parte ya la logre, pero lo que no he conseguido es que el textbox recupere el foco, ya lo intente con el evento Deactivate y con el Activate incluso con el evento Leave, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Este es el código que uso para que el formulario se quede siempre encima de las demas aplicaciones.

**Clase**

```
class Encima
{
    //Constantes para SetWindowsPost
    //Valores wFlags
    const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;
    const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
    const int SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x10;
    const int wFlags = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;

    //Valores de hwndInsertAfter
    const int HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
    const int HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2;

    [DllImport("user32.DLL")]
    private extern static void SetWindowPos(
        int HWnd,
        int hWInsertAfter,
        int X,
        int Y,
        int cx,
        int cy,
        int wFlags);

    public static void SiempreEncima(int handle)
    {
        SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, wFlags);
    }

    public static void NoSiempreEncima(int handle)
    {
        SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, wFlags);
    }
}
```

**Formulario**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Encima.SiempreEncima(this.Handle.ToInt32());//aqui invoco la clase para que el formulario siempre este arriba de las demas aplicaciones
        textBox1.Focus();//le doy el foco al textbox
    }
    
    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //se supone que cuando el formulario se desactive, se activa otra vez y le paso el foco al textbox otra vez
        this.Activate();
        textBox1.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: quieres controlar componentes del form principal, desde un form secundario?

Comment: No, solo utilizo un form, lo que quiero hacer es, por ejemplo, si yo hago clic fuera del form, que el form se vuelva a activar, y pasarle el foco a un textbox